# Is it possible to change runtime Spark configurations separately for different driver threads?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My application consists of several worker threads which execute Spark queries concurrently. Each query has a set of Spark SQL configuration parameters that are optimal for it (for instance: `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`), but since all the queries are executed concurrently, I'm unable to control the configuration values for each query separately.

This example illustrates and application with 2 concurrent threads, each running the same spark query but with different values for `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`:

```py
import time
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
default_num_partitions = spark.conf.get('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions')
print(f'default spark.sql.shuffle.partitions={default_num_partitions}')


def run_loop_in_thread(new_num_partitions: int):
    for i in range(10):
        spark.conf.set('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', str(new_num_partitions))
        time.sleep(0.5)  # just to simulate something longer
        actual_num_partitions = spark.range(100).repartition("id").rdd.getNumPartitions()
        print(f'expected={new_num_partitions} ; actual={actual_num_partitions}')
        time.sleep(0.5)  # just to simulate something longer
        spark.conf.set('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', str(default_num_partitions))


pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()
pool.submit(run_loop_in_thread, 3)
pool.submit(run_loop_in_thread, 5)
pool.shutdown(wait=True)
```

The output of this example will be something like this (due to the non-deterministic nature of this code, you might see something slightly different):

```
default spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=200
expected=5 ; actual=5
expected=3 ; actual=5
expected=3 ; actual=3
expected=5 ; actual=3
...
```

It seems that the `spark.conf` instance is shared among all threads. Is there a way to make it thread-local?. My objective is to assure that in the example above, the `expected` will always be the same as the `actual`, like so:

```
default spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=200
expected=5 ; actual=5
expected=3 ; actual=3
expected=3 ; actual=3
expected=5 ; actual=5
...
```

Comment: why are you sharing threads in **one Spark application**? Wouldn't it be much easier if you have multiple Spark applications?

Comment: This is an over-simplified example of my real application which runs multiple structured streaming queries on a single Spark application with fair scheduling, this way I have much better control over the allocation and utilisation of my cluster's resources.